# how can i return value with multiple pages.. in laravel the code i given below

Tags: laravel, routes, reactive

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $email=$request->email;
    $password=$request->password;
    $students=Student::where('email','=',$email)
    ->where('password','=',$password)
    ->first();

    if($students){
        // Session::put('email',$student->email);
        // Session::put('id',$student->id);
        //dd($students);
        return redirect()->route('student.dashboard');

    }



    else{
        Session()->flash('success','Invalid Email & and password');
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }

}
```

I want to return this `$student` value to different pages. as like as student view pages and update student pages how can i return this value to different pages.
Thank you

Comment: You can do like this  return view('create')->with(compact('student'));

Comment: no it is not work

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, also write your route for student pages.

Comment: I think you want to pass the same data to multiple views within your application you could use View Composers or Pass the same value to all view file you could use share in the AppServiceProviders boot function.

Comment: Yes, you got it but I can not  :(   okay i but I will try :)  but in this way can pass data to different way :)